# Solved inverse Galois problem for $\mathbb{C}(z)$ seems to contradict the theory about Liouvillian extensions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, galois-theory, differential-algebra

The theory about Liouvillian extensions tells us that a Picard-Vessiot extension $L \supset k$ is Liouvillian if and only if the identity component $G^°$ of $G = Gal(L / k)$ is solvable.

I think I found a Liouvillian extension, that has a non-solvable subgroup, which seems to be absurd. I don't see any mistake, so please help me out!

**Counterexample** Let $k = \mathbb{C}$ be the complex functions with zero-derivation, i.e. it is its own field of constants. Let $\mathbb{C}(z)$ be the function field in one variable, with the common derivation $z' = 1$. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem#Partial_results) or [this paper](http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~fehm/papers/Cz.pdf) the inverse Galois problem for $\mathbb{C}(z)$ is solved positively, so we can choose an algebraic extension $L \supset \mathbb{C}(z)$, such that $H := Gal(L / \mathbb{C}(z))$ is not solvable (e.g. $H = A_5$). Now $L$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{C}(z)$, so there is a unique way to extend the derivation to $L$. In particular, $L / \mathbb{C}(z)$ is a Picard-Vessiot extension, so $L / \mathbb{C}$ is one as well. Choosing a primitve element $t \in L$ such that $L = \mathbb{C}(z, t)$, we see that $L / \mathbb{C}$ is in fact Liouvillian.
Its differential Galois group $Gal(L / \mathbb{C})$ is connected, because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, but it also contains the closed non-solvable subgroup $H = Gal(L / \mathbb{C}(z)) \subset Gal(L / \mathbb{C})$.

So this seems to contradict the fact that $Gal(L / \mathbb{C})$ should be solvable.

PS: If someone comes up with such an explicit extension $L \supset \mathbb{C}(z)$ I would be grateful, because this simplifies the argument quite a bit. I had not yet time to think about this.

Comment: I know next to nothing about differential Galois groups, so I'm the wrong person to judge. But, why should the group $H=Gal(L/\Bbb{C}(z))$ of *field automorphisms* be a subgroup of the group of *automorphisms of differential fields* $Gal(L/\Bbb{C})$? The extension $L/\Bbb{C}(z)$ is simple (it is finite and separable). Therefore any differentiation on $\Bbb{C}(z)$ has a unique extension to a differentiation of $L$. I'm probably very wrong about this, and missing something big. Something just does not compute (for me) :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen As you said, there is a unique differentiation of $L$, making $L / \mathbb{C}(z)$ into a differential extension. Thus $\mathbb{C}(z)$ is a differential field between $L$ and $\mathbb{C}$. By (differential) Galois theory we get an inclusion $Gal^d(L / \mathbb{C}(z)) \subset Gal^d(L / \mathbb{C})$ of differential Galois groups (here marked by ${}^d$). Now the point is that (classical) Galois extensions are also Picard-Vessiot extensions, and then the classical Galois group coincides with the differential Galois group, i.e. $Gal^d(L / \mathbb{C}(z)) = Gal(L / \mathbb{C}(z))$.

Comment: This is **Exercise 1.24** in van der Put's *Galois Theory of Linear Differential Equations*.

Comment: Thanks. I made category errors. Probably several :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I discussed this with my professor, and our consensus was, that $\mathbb{C}(z,l) / \mathbb{C}$ is *not* a Liouvillian extension. To give a counterexample, take $l$ to be a square root of $z$, i.e. $l^2 = z$. Then $l$ generated $\mathbb{C}(z,l) = \mathbb{C}(l)$, but will never satisfy a differential equation

$$ l^{(n)} + c_1l^{(n-1)} + \dotsc + c_{0}l = 0,$$
because differentiating $l$ produces higher powers of $l^{-1}$.

Comment: *differentiating, not derivating